# How to append dynamically generated HTML table at the end of div, on selection of drop down present in the same div?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck in the following problem:

I have this div in html:

```
<div id="PieChart">
    <label>Title of the pie chart:</label>
    <input id="pieChartTitle" type="text">
    <select id="xAxisList" onChange="showAxis('x')">
        <option hidden="true"></option>                         
        <option value="time">Time</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

OnChange of drop down list I am calling a Javascript function, showAxis('x'), which dynamically generates HTML table. The code is below:

```
function showAxis(coordinate){
    var axisList = coordinate + "AxisList";
    var v = document.getElementById(axisList);
    selectedAxisType = v.options[v.selectedIndex].value;

    var dataArray = new Array();
    selectedChartType = "PieChart";    
    var selectedChart = document.getElementById(selectedChartType);

    var tr, td;
    var table, tableBody;
    var dropdown, opt, i;

    table = document.createElement('TABLE');

    dataArray = ["Years", "Seasons", "Months", "Weeks", "Days"];

    table.setAttribute("id", "time"+axisList+"Table");
    table.setAttribute("class", "time"+axisList+"Table");
    table.width='100%';

    tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    dropdown = document.createElement("select");
    dropdown.setAttribute("id", "time"+axisList);
    tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    td = document.createElement('TD');
    td.width='40%';
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Time selection on the basis of:"));
    tr.appendChild(td);

    opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.hidden="true";
    dropdown.options.add(opt);

    for (i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++){
        td = document.createElement('TD');
        opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.text = dataArray[i];
        opt.value = dataArray[i];
        dropdown.options.add(opt);
        td.appendChild(dropdown);

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }// END of Outer for loop
selectedChart.appendChild(table);
}// END of showAxis()
```

PROBLEM: This dynamically generated table in showAxis(coordinate) method gets appended before "xAxisList" drop down list, I want this TABLE as whole to be appended after the drop down list ("xAxisList").

I have spent much time on few blogs, but couldn't find anything helpful. I would be really thankful if someone helps me solving this issue. Thanks allot for your time and reading my question.

Comment: Your dropdown is a row of your table, added at the end, so it will always be "below" the table.  It's actually inside your table.  You need to pull the dropdown out of the table.

Comment: No I am not concerned about the drop down which is being dynamically generated inside the table. My problem is that this dynamic TABLE as a whole gets appended above the "xAxisList" (drop down list), which calls showAxis(coordinate) on change!

Comment: oh so when they select the dropdown it shows the table and then the dropdown they just used is now below?  is that what your saying ?

Comment: yes exactly, TABLE gets appended above "xAxisList" (drop down list), but I want it to be appended at the end!

Comment: What version of jquery are you using.  It works in 2.0.2

Comment: I put the onchange in the jquery instead of html, but other than that appears to work....    http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/vkpb2ubm/

Comment: I am using jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76744/discussion-between-amir-and-notorious-pet0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this JS FIDDLE v1.9.1 working with onchange in javascript instead of html.

[JSFIDDLE v1](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/vkpb2ubm/1/)

```
(function($){

$(function(){  //document.ready


    $("#xAxisList").on('change', function() {
       showAxis('x'); 
    });

function showAxis(coordinate){
var axisList = coordinate + "AxisList";
var v = document.getElementById(axisList);
selectedAxisType = v.options[v.selectedIndex].value;

var dataArray = new Array();
selectedChartType = "PieChart";    
var selectedChart = document.getElementById(selectedChartType);

var tr, td;
var table, tableBody;
var dropdown, opt, i;

table = document.createElement('TABLE');

dataArray = ["Years", "Seasons", "Months", "Weeks", "Days"];

table.setAttribute("id", "time"+axisList+"Table");
table.setAttribute("class", "time"+axisList+"Table");
table.width='100%';

tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);

dropdown = document.createElement("select");
dropdown.setAttribute("id", "time"+axisList);
tr = document.createElement('TR');
tableBody.appendChild(tr);

td = document.createElement('TD');
td.width='40%';
td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Time selection on the basis of:"));
tr.appendChild(td);

opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.hidden="true";
dropdown.options.add(opt);

for (i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++){
    td = document.createElement('TD');
    opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = dataArray[i];
    opt.value = dataArray[i];
    dropdown.options.add(opt);
    td.appendChild(dropdown);

    tr.appendChild(td);
}// END of Outer for loop
selectedChart.appendChild(table);
}// END of showAxis

      });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: No this is not the issue. My problem is that this dynamic TABLE as a whole gets appended above the "xAxisList" (drop down list), which calls showAxis(coordinate) on change! I want this TABLE get appended below "xAxisList" (drop down list)!

Comment: @Amir answer has been updated.  I believe this should work.  Check the JS Fiddle link, I removed the onchange from the html and put into javascript/jquery.

Comment: Thanks allot for your time mate. :)